# Possible to dynamically change Doctrine Entity mappings?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have a PSR-loaded package that defines a series of relationships around a 'User' entity it provides.

In many of the use cases where you use this package, you may want to keep all entities intact, but, substitute your own User entity.

As concrete example, the package gives me this Entity (using Annotations here to keep things clear):

```
namespace CirclicalUser\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * An example entity that represents an action rule.
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="acl_actions_users")
 *
 */
class UserActionRule
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CirclicalUser\Entity\ActionRule", inversedBy="user_exceptions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="action_rule_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $action_rule;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CirclicalUser\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

}
```

Given the above, is there any way I could supplant the user relationship in UserActionRule::$user, that targets *CirclicalUser\Entity\User*, with my own user: **Acme\Entity\User** (assuming it is a Doctrine Entity in its own right)

e.g., pretend PHP:

```
function onBoostrap( $e ){
    DoctrineMagic::getMapping(UserActionRule::class)->get('user')->getManyToOne()->setTargetEntity(Acme\Entity\User::class);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried EventSubscriber to `loadClassMetadata` event? You can find great inspiration in [SoftDeletableSubscriber](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors/blob/14a4d19e808c955da1b0962b3cf0bdc9f69c61f0/src/ORM/SoftDeletable/SoftDeletableSubscriber.php#L89-L107)

Comment: Was just going to point, that I'd solved it using loadClassMetadata!  I'll post my solve below.

Comment: Great job! Please accept your answer so it the question is marked as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this by listening to the loadClassMetadata event.

```
namespace CirclicalUser\Listener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;
use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;

class UserEntityListener implements EventSubscriber
{
    const DEFAULT_ENTITY = 'CirclicalUser\Entity\User';

    private $userEntity;

    public function __construct($userEntity)
    {
        $this->userEntity = $userEntity;
    }

    public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return ['loadClassMetadata'];
    }

    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        /** @var \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata $classMetadata */
        $classMetadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();

        if ($this->userEntity == self::DEFAULT_ENTITY) {
            return;
        }

        switch ($classMetadata->getName()) {
            case 'CirclicalUser\Entity\UserActionRule':
                $classMetadata->associationMappings['user']['targetEntity'] = $this->userEntity;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This listener successfully substitutes the mapping for the user-defined entity class.

Adding the listener (Zend Framework) was trivial:

```
'doctrine' => [
    'eventmanager' => [
        'orm_default' => [
            'subscribers' => [
                UserEntityListener::class,
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

Separately, in service manager config:

```
'service_manager' => [

    'invokables' => [
        UserAuthenticationLogMapper::class => UserAuthenticationLogMapper::class,
    ],

    'factories' => [
        UserEntityListener::class => UserEntityListenerFactory::class,
    ],

],
```